Can't display nested SOQL data in Conga Word template
On Salesforce, I have an SOQL Query
select fferpcore__Quantity__c, (SELECT Qunatity__c FROM ffbc__Usage__r) FROM fferpcore__BillingDocumentLineItem__c WHERE fferpcore__BillingDocument__c = '{pv0}'

Here is what it looks like on the Conga Word Template

I'm getting the Qty. column perfectly, however Consumption is always empty.
Tried Conga Template Builder as well but wasn't able to figure it out. The Conga Query and Solution are all updated. What can I update the Template syntax with?
Thanks
